# Cannot set session values in Spring MVC project using weblogic

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, tomcat, weblogic12c

I have a controller class that is taking in HttpServletRequest request as a parameter. Then I get the session from the request and set an attribute on it... Then the request goes onto the next page. Then when the user click the button and I go back to the controller class to get the value from the session again the value is gone.

This works perfectly inside Tomcat but not in Weblogic (I am using version 12)

It is pretty straight forward

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("userName", userNameInUpperCase);
```

and then again which is null

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("userName");
```

Is there something specifically that needs to be done in Weblogic to have this enabled.

I read one post where is says i should create a weblogic.xml file cookie secure = false but it still doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
xmlns:j2ee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90
http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

<session-descriptor>
        <debug-enabled>true</debug-enabled>
        <persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</persistent-store-type>
        <url-rewriting-enabled>true</url-rewriting-enabled>
        <cookies-enabled>true</cookies-enabled>
        <cookie-secure>false</cookie-secure>
</session-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: Is your environment cluster based or single node? Sessions are not cluster safe.

Comment: @erhun My project runs on a default domain that I created with the Weblogic config wizard with all default options and I dropped my war in the auto deploy folder. This is completely standalone running from my local pc only and will never go to a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the session ID between the set and the get call executions to see if you are getting back a different session. Also make sure you aren't disabling the session on the JSP with a page directive.